# New General Chat Room

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat

Not really a question but I've just created a new general chat room called Buddhism Chat (not original sorry) to replace the general chat room that got frozen. Someone was asking about it on another meta question.

I think we need to post something every 7 days at least to stop this one freezing up. I'll try to post something in there periodically even if it it is a bit trivial. Appreciate any contributions if anyone wants to post. I think it's a shame not to have a general room for people if they need it.

Comment: Moderators can un-freeze chat rooms - just post on Meta and someone will get to it. Would you like me to un-freeze the original room, or would you rather stay in this new room?

Comment: @abbyhairboat I'd prefer restoring the old chatroom, because then we don't have to setup any feeds again. But that's just me.

Comment: @abbyhairboat please that sounds good. Can we unfreeze the old chat room. I'll delete the one I created if I can

Comment: Yeah! Can you drop me a link to it?

Comment: @abbyhairboat Thanks. The link is http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15162/buddhism Cheers

Comment: All set. Have at it :)

Comment: @abbyhairboat brill cheers